# How to run a script python on multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple .txt files in a folder (file1, file2, file3, file4, file5,....) and  I need to run on a large number of files.

I've created this code to reorder and make some changes ... I would like to apply it on multiple txt files from a original folder(path) and save them separately into another folder (inside the last folder) or another path

Can someone please help?

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import glob
    import datetime
    #from datetime import datetime

    df1=pd.read_csv("D:\\Spyder2019\\38A.txt", sep='\s+') 

#############################################33#
#to change name of column and add Temp ms column

    df1=df1.rename(index=str, columns={"Temps":"Heure", "Force":"Force(N)", "Vitesse":"Vitesse(RPM)", "Puissance":"Puissance(w)","Torque":"Torque(N/m)","Angle":"Angle(deg)"})#to change name Temps to Heure

    dtemp=df1['Heure']#to change datetime values into seconds and microseconds in Heure

    dtemp=pd.to_datetime(df1.Heure) #change to datetime values float 

    dtemp1=dtemp.dt.microsecond #dtemp1 object in microseconds with 6 decimals

    dtempms=dtemp1 / 1000000 #dtemp1 object into 2 decimals

    dtemp2=dtemp.dt.second #dtemp2 object in seconds

    df1['Temps_ms']= dtempms + dtemp2 #add second and microseconds to the object

    #################################################
    # to transform the Heure data into sec and microsec

    df1=df1[['Date','NoBille','Heure','Temps_ms','Force(N)','Vitesse(RPM)','Puissance(w)','Torque(N/m)','Angle(deg)']]# reorder the dataframe

    io=df1.iat[0,3]
    #to transform the Heure data into seconds ans microseconds

    df1['Temps(ms)'] = np.where(df1['Temps_ms'] - io <0, df1['Temps_ms'] + 60 - io, df1['Temps_ms'] -io)

    df1=df1.drop(columns=['Temps_ms'])#to eliminate column Temps_ms

    df1=df1[['Date','NoBille','Heure','Temps(ms)','Force(N)','Vitesse(RPM)','Puissance(w)','Torque(N/m)','Angle(deg)']]# to reorder the final dataframe

    ##############################################################################
    print(df1.head())

    df1.to_csv('data1.txt', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this script can be applied to all databases that you have in your "input folder" you can pass the DB name as argument to python script:

```py
import sys

#...your other imports...

### take the first argument passed in commmand line as db_name and second as output_file name
db_name = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = sys.argv[2]
df1 = pd.read_csv(db_name, sep='\s+') 

#...rest of your script...

df1.to_csv(output_filename, index = False)
```

and then yuo can easily call the python script over the files in the input directory with an external loop, as ex. in bash:

```sh
mkdir <output-dir>
ls <input-dir> | while read file; do
    output_filename="<output-dir>/$file.output.txt"
    python <your-script-name> $file $output_filename
done
```

and it will automatically take the files, operate the python script and write them down in output-dir with the specified extension

Comment: Thanks!! but I still have problems. Any another option?

Comment: write what you tried and exactly the error you encountered (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)